# Can't import Date dd/mm/yyyy in crm

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I have some records that I need to import into the CRM.
The format of dates in CRM is dd/mm/yyyy; and the format in Excel file is dd/mm/yyyy.
after importing, records with dates like 01/01/2016 are imported but those with dates like 31/07/2016 are not and the CRM give me the folowing error:

The source data is not in the required format.

When I import from Excel Online, it work, but from a file it doesn't work and give the error.
Thanks in advance for you help.
[image]

Comment: Did you mean `016` instead of `2016`, e.g. `yyy`?

Comment: I edited to yyyy. thks

Comment: What are the system settings for the date time. It is probably trying to read them as the american date format; So thevalidation fails when it cannot find the 31 month

Comment: I added a screenshot of my system settings. thks

Comment: If I remember rightly, you also have to ensure that the user accounts which run the services also have the right localisation too.

Answer (score 0):

Add the correct localization settings for the specific user that is importing.